# What kind of wear does a spark plug cable go through?

Tags: electrical, maintenance, sparkplugs, wear, spark-plug-wires

I'm about to change spark plugs on my car, and given the cost of getting just the plugs or plugs + cables, I'm considering just keeping the current ones.

The car runs *fine* (well, it's consuming way too much fuel), so I'm interested in knowing what kind of wear they go through that would make them fail or degrade performance.

The car is a 2010 Fiat Uno 1L, possibly with original spark plugs and about 46k mi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark plug cables can suffer from a few different things:

- cumulative heat stress from being near the engine
- cumulative electrical stress from the high voltages they carry
- chafing against nearby things

Normally, I inspect them whenever I replace the plugs. Look for cracks or breaks in the outside insulator, damage to the boot, and if you have a multi-meter you can test their resistance.

Comment: So, if the resistance is within spec and they don't have any cracks, changing them would merely be a preventative measure?

Comment: More like a waste of money :) I only replace spark plug cables if there's something wrong with them.

Comment: Could you point to where one would find the resistance rating?

Comment: A repair manual for your specific make and model (Haynes, Chilton)

Answer (score 1):

The most common type of spark plug cables is carbon core wires. In this kind the carbon eventually burns away and the wires can no longer transmit a good signal. If you don't have carbon wires, the main thing that could go wrong would just be a hole in the insulation or boot which could be caused by any number of things. Test your wires' resistance with a multimeter before you replace them. Another thing you can do to see if they are bad is wait until its dark and then spray the wire and boots with a water bottle. Any sparks arcing out of the wires or boots means they are bad.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the connector that mates to the top of the plug fail before.  This caused an intermittent misfire and general poor running that weren't fixed by new plugs -- then I looked at the ends of the cables and saw why.

This was in a 90s car so things might have changed since then (it was the last petrol car I did much work on).